# Bottom/undefined value in F#?

Tags: f#

There is a convenient [undefined](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom) value in Haskell that can be used as a stub for yet to be defined functions/paths in code. Is there anything like it in F#?

Answer (score 12):

To be concrete, you can define such a value like this:

```
let undefined<'T> : 'T = failwith "Not implemented yet"

let stub1 (x : int) : float = undefined
let stub2 (x : 'T) : 'T = undefined
```

Beware that F# evaluation is strict. If you bind `undefined` to a top-level value, it will throw an exception during evaluation.

Answer (score 7):

I think

```
failwith "Not implemented"
```

would be pretty much equivalent

Answer (score 5):

More specific and .NET-friendly way

```
let undefined<'T> : 'T = raise (NotImplementedException())
```

allows you to skip typing a message and still differentiate this exception from other ones in a catch block or stack trace.

Comment: But as @pad pointed out, this needs to be a function `let undefined () = ...`, otherwise the exception will be thrown immediately on binding the name.