# F# try-with combined with reraise() returns valid type. Why?

Tags: exception, f#, try-catch

I am trying to figure out the try-with in F#. And as i understood it, then the the return type of try must be identical to the return type of with.

But why is it then that when i do something like this:

```
 let safeIndexTry (anArray : array<'a>) (i : int) = 
  try 
    Array. item i anArray
  with
    | :? System.IndexOutOfRangeException as ex -> printfn "%s" ex.Message 
                                                  reraise()
```

then as i can figure it. then reraise() turns the return value to a valid type. in this case an int. But why is that? and is that for all types reraise will do that?

In general i find it a bit problematic that the two must have the same return type. I mean usualy you want to calculate some value and if it is unable to then catch an exception throwing a string message. Can some give me any guidance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reraise` is defined like this:

```fsharp
reraise : unit -> 'T
```

That means its result type fits the type of the encompassing function from which it is returned. Its return value is more or less meaningless because of the exception being thrown. In languages like Haskell it can be thought of as [bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337249/bottom-undefined-value-in-f).

Since the function has to have the same result type, a more idiomatic value to return would be the `Option` type. You can then return `None` if an exception is caught, and a `Some goodValue` when the operation is successful. This idiom is much preferred over using exceptions to handle control flow because all callers must explicitly handle both the `None` and `Some` cases, rather than having to wrap all calling code with exception handling wrappers.

Here is what your function would look like if converted to use `Option`:

```fsharp
let safeIndexTry (anArray : array<'a>) (i : int) : 'a option = 
  try 
    Some <| Array. item i anArray
  with
    | :? System.IndexOutOfRangeException as ex -> None
```

Comment: can you illustrate this none, some exception handling ? I really would like to understand this.

Comment: I've added an example of using `Option`

Comment: And then if going that way I would very much recommend https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/ Its the "same" as Option, but maybe more "correct" when thinking exceptions. But yes, its of course dependent on usage, preferences and what not... Mind that the "next question" is "how do I manage to stop matching for Some/None (or other variants if ROPing) all over the place", so some further reading/testing may be necessary...